# c# event, unregister without prior register

Tags: c#, events

Weirdly I haven't been able to find an answer in the doc or on the web although it seems to be a simple question:

Imagine I registered to a c# event in a conditional block:

```
void Execute()
{
    if(loader.AlreadyCompleted)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        loader.Completed += DoSomething;
    }
}
```

In this example, a loader will trigger the `Completed` event. If it already happended `AlreadyCompleted` will be true, otherwise it is false and I want to register to the  `Completed` event in order to wait before executing `DoSomething`.

Now imagine that I have an Abort function that could be trigger anytime.
In the Abort function I will need to deregister from the `Completed` event.

```
void Abort()
{
    loader.Completed -= DoSomething;
}
```

What will happen if the loader was ready at startup and we never executed the line `loader.Completed += DoSomething;` ? **Can we deregister an event that hasn't been registered?** Is there a way to check if we are registered? What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: Have you even tried it? This question look too theoretical to me which makes it too broad.

Comment: I hadn't try it when asking. Since I didn't find the answer in StackOverflow I decided to ask, since I'm surely not the only one looking for this info, having the info here can be helpful. I just see that it is a duplicate. That's because I searched using the term "registering" instead of "subscribing", my mistake

Comment: Please read on what [mcve] is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try to unregister an event that was never registered nothing will happen. This is due to the idea that when you call `loader.Completed -= DoSomething;` it’s really just saying `loaded.Completed = (Completed)Delegate.Remove(DoSomething)`.
When you try to remove an event handler that was never added or is not there Delegate.Remove will just return null, which sets the `loaded.Complete = null`.

Comment: To back this up check [this online example](http://rextester.com/RGA8745)